# Python pymysql - iterate through mysql table key and value

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am new to python pymysql (I used before Ruby with Mysql2 gem), 
I want to get the key and the value from mysql table and do some actions:

For example:

```
dbconnection = pymysql.connect(host=mysql_hostname, user=mysql_username, password=mysql_pass, db=mysql_schema, charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = dbconnection.cursor()
_SQL = (""" 
        select * ...
        """)

cursor.execute(_SQL)
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    print(row)
    print("\n")
    # How can I access each key and each value for example: STATUS is the value and 3 is the key
    # I want to do something like this: 
    #'if the value of 'CAP' > 1: change the value of status where the ID key
    #   cursor.execute("UPDATE <table> SET row[STATUS]='1' WHERE ID='row[ID]'")
```

Output:

```
{'STATUS': 3, 'ID': 10, 'CAP': 1}
{'STATUS': 3, 'ID': 11, 'CAP': 2}
{'STATUS': 3, 'ID': 12, 'CAP': 3}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with the key and value **of a table**? A table can have multiple columns.

Comment: I update my question, I want to be able to access the key name and the value name for each result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `row` is simply a **`dict`ionary**. So you can use `.items()` to generate a sequence of key and value:

```
for row in result:
    for key,value in row.items():
        print('The key is %s'%key)
        print('The value is %s'%value)
```

Comment: right :), it is a bit confusing when switching from Ruby to Python, do you maybe know if its ok to use 'pymysql' instead of `MySQL Connector` ?

Comment: @Berlin: unfortunately I'm not very familiar with database frameworks, etc.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example. With `cursor. fetchall()` this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Using pymysql, you need to declare the cursor as a dictionary type like below:

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="myraces")
#  cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor(connection)

query = "SELECT * FROM `races`"
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    for key, value in row.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking for is this:

```
for row in result:
    if row["CAP"] > 1:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE <table> SET row[STATUS]='1' WHERE ID='row[ID]'")
    else:
        continue
```